# How to create a blog category in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am able to fetch the blog category name from the phpmyadmin database.
I want to link the category name

categories.component.html:

```
    <div class="right-widget categories">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <ul>
           <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
             {{category.name}}
          </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
```

blogpost.service.ts:

```
export class BlogpostService {
  getFeaturedBlogs() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

  ServerUrl = 'http://localhost/demo/blogger/';
  errorData: {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBlog(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<Blogpost>(this.ServerUrl + 'api/blog/' + id)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

getRecentBlogs() {
    return this.http.get<Blogpost>(this.ServerUrl + 'api/recent_blogs').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

getCategories() {
    return this.http.get<Category>(this.ServerUrl + 'api/categories').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

```
categories.component.ts
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

      categories: Category;
      error: {};

      constructor(private blogpostService: BlogpostService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.blogpostService.getCategories().subscribe(
          (data: Category) => this.categories = data,
          error => this.error = error
          );
      }
    }
```

Could you please help me? I am unable to link the category name?

Comment: I don't see you defining the property `categories` anywhere.

Comment: I think you want to type cast the response to Category array object. If you've defined the Category as class, it won't work. You need to create an interface with the required properties. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154215/5396181

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a file categories.component.ts.

In constructor of this file, you inject a service

```
constructor(private service: BlogpostService) {}
```

And have a variable

```
categories: Category[];
```

Then, for example, in ngOnInit method, 
you call service method and get categories data

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.service.getCategories().subscribe(
   data => {
     this.categories = data
   }
 )
}
```

Also looks like that getCategories return an Array.
If it true you need to change in getCategories() method

```
return this.http.get<Category>
```

on

```
return this.http.get<Category[]>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I have update the code. Can you please check the above mention code?

Comment: @PamuShinde Define a Category interface with the require properties. Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154215/5396181

Comment: The code looks good. Can you pls also show Category interface?
In categories.component.html you iterate throw categories, so it needs to be an array. But if it a single object you cannot do that.